# Expected expression on willSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

In my `UITableView`, I have 2 rows. I'm trying to disable the 2nd row and so I have done the following shown in the picture. When I run the program, although the row is not able to push onto another view, the blue highlight still flashes when I click on it.

So, I have put the bit of code also shown below in the `if (indexPath.row == 1)` expression, but an error has come up.

How can I get rid of the error?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put

```
 {

}
```

after `if` and then put the code inside and then write `else`.. :D rookie mistake.

```
if(indexPath.row==1){
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
return nil;
}else
 return indexPath;
```

Comment: You are right, I am a rookie. Haha. I will accept your answer after the time limit :)

Comment: To expand the answer, the only case in which you can skip the { } on an if/for/while is when the code is only 1 line, 2 or more lines and you need { } (For example, your else will work fine)